# GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/dataFood 404 (Not Found) trying to print my sql data into my html

Tags: javascript, get, http-status-code-404

my problem is im trying to connect to mysql and im using express.js server and the problem is this GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/dataFood 404 (Not Found) .
I have  2 codes the client side and the server side ill print everthing here to see what is the problem.

**server side code in javascript:
**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// MySQL database connection configuration
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'rootuser',
    database: 'foodDatabase',
    port: 3306
});

// Connect to the MySQL database
connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting to MySQL database:', err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected to MySQL database as ID ' + connection.threadId);
});

// Serve static files (HTML, CSS, JavaScript)
app.use(express.static('public'));


// Route to fetch data from the database
app.get('/dataFood', (req, res) => {
    // Perform a query to fetch data
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM meals', (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error executing query:', error);
            return res.status(500).send('Error fetching data from database');
        }

        // Send the fetched data as JSON response
        res.json(results);
    });
});

// Start the server
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

**client side code in javascript:
**

```
fetch('/dataFood')
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Data received from server:', data);

        // Create a container for the data
        const dataContainer = document.getElementById('dataContainer');

        // Iterate over the data and create an element for each item
        data.forEach(item => {
            // Create a new div element for the item
            const itemDiv = document.createElement('div');
            itemDiv.className = 'item';

            // Create a new h2 element for the item name
            const itemName = document.createElement('h2');
            itemName.textContent = item.name; // Assuming 'name' is a property of the item

            // Create a new p element for the item description
            const itemDescription = document.createElement('p');
            itemDescription.textContent = item.description; // Assuming 'description' is a property    of the item

            // Append the item name and description to the item div
            itemDiv.appendChild(itemName);
            itemDiv.appendChild(itemDescription);

            // Append the item div to the data container
            dataContainer.appendChild(itemDiv);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
    });
```

**this is the html code:
**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Data Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Data from MySQL Database</h1>
  <div id="dataContainer" class="data-container"></div> <!-- Container for data -->
  <script src="script.js"></script> <!-- Include your JavaScript file -->
</body>

</html>
```

forgot to add an error in the client side code:
fetch('/dataFood') <<< is underline red
and also here:
.catch(error => {
console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);

this is the output I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD9Qj.jpg)

this is my github: https://github.com/SulimanGR/Async

feel free to view my code for further code inspection.

Comment: 404 is a Not Found error. Your JavaScript code is looking for a page called `dataFood, `, but for whatever reason it's not there. Maybe the file is in the wrong place, or it needs an extension, or your router is misbehaving, or some other reason. We can't tell from what you've posted here.

Comment: I think he/she has provided enough info. The issue is the port.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm., from a quick scan 404 means the page doesn't exist. It's easy to overlook errors as a programmer but I highly recommend looking at the errors.

A page not found means when the client requests a resource it's not there. Your route appears to be correct but the port in the url does not. You're asking for a resource in your url for port 5500 but in your code you have port = 3000.

Comment: I appreciate your answer  and I edited the listen port to 5500 still the same forgot to add an error in the client side code: fetch('/dataFood') <<< is underline red and also here: .catch(error => { console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);

Comment: Try starting your web server and typing netstat -tupln | grep tcp

Comment: tell me if you see your webserver listed there